# Vector iterator not dereferencable?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

I'm getting that error with this code:

```
for(std::vector<AguiTimedEvent*>::iterator it = timedEvents.begin();
    it != timedEvents.end();)
{
    if((*it)->expired())
    {
        (*it)->timedEventCallback();
        delete (*it);

        it = timedEvents.erase(it);
    }
    else
        it++;
}
```

What could be the problem?

the timed event sometimes pushes a new one in when its callback is called, that might do it

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error text?

Comment: Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable

(debug assertion failed)

Comment: Does `timedEventCallback` or `AguiTimedEvent`'s destructor directly or indirectly modify `timedEvents`?

Comment: the timed event sometimes pushes a new one in when its callback is called, that might do it

Comment: Does it identify a specific line number?

Comment: If you modify your collection while iterating it (with your callback), there's no guarantee iterators will still be valid afterwards. That might be your problem.

Comment: Is this on VS 2010? There was a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=545013&wa=wsignin1.0) added in this version of the compiler afflicting `std::vector::erase`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looping through a vector and the callback function causes the vector to be added to, then all iterators into the vector may be invalidated including the loop variable `it`.

In this case (where the callback modifies the vector) you are probably better off using an index as your loop variable.

You probably need to do some thorough analysis of the design to make sure that you aren't going to create any unexpected infinite loops.

E.g.

```
for(std::vector<AguiTimedEvent*>::size_type n = 0;
    n < timedEvents.size();)
{
    if(timedEvents[n]->expired())
    {
        timedEvents[n]->timedEventCallback();
        delete timedEvents[n];

        timedEvents.erase(timedEvents.begin() + n);
    }
    else
        n++;
}
```

Comment: Then how will I erase an expired element?

Answer (score 3):

> the timed event sometimes pushes a new one in when its callback is called, that might do it

Yes.

If you add an element to the vector, `it` may be invalidated.

Comment: @Milo: That would depend on what you want the results to be. Where are the new elements added in the vector? Do you want to iterate over them too? It's suspect to be adding elements to a container during a removal pass.

Comment: @Milo, push the element onto a temporary vector and merge it into the primary one when the loop is finished.

Comment: @Mark, @Milo: or perhaps use a `deque` instead of a `vector`. Appending to a `deque` never invalidates earlier iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

> the timed event sometimes pushes a new
>   one in when its callback is called,
>   that might do it

Yes, that is very definitely unsafe. If the vector has to resize, then all of it's pointers and iterators would be invalidated. You should never, ever insert into the middle of a vector whilst it's being iterated through, that will cause death. Maybe if you converted to a numerical for loop, the problem would be solved.

Comment: I may be being dumb but why isn't it safe? `it` is replaced with the return value of `erase` and `.end()` is recalculated in every loop iteration.

Comment: @user470379: I can read the comment you put on the other answer, you know.

Comment: Not if it gets deleted, like it just did ;)

Comment: @user470379: Pretty sure that, as having over 10k rep, I can infact view deleted answers and their associated comments. As for the erase() safety, then I agree with you - I can't see how it's invalid either. However, there is extremely definitely no other source of error in the OP's code, it's a pretty simple loop, so unless you want me to conclude that his STL implementation or compiler is bugged, there is only one thing to look at.

Comment: Just because you have over 10k rep doesn't mean everybody looking at the answers/comments will. However, now that you have completely rewritten your answer, the original comment is unneeded.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you insert in the middle or at the end, it's still unsafe. I'm sure you know that, but your wording leaves some ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `std::remove_copy_if` and `std::remove_if`: (Haven't tested this but it should give you the idea...)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

//I'm sure you probably already have a delete functor lying around, right?
// No? Well here's one for you....
struct Deleter : public std::unary_function<AguiTimedEvent*, void>
{
    void operator()(AguiTimedEvent* toNuke)
    {
        delete toNuke;
    }
};

std::vector<AguiTimedEvent*> toRun;
std::remove_copy_if(timedEvents.begin(), timedEvents.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(toRun), std::not1(std::mem_fun(&AguiTimedEvent::expired)));
timedEvents.erase(std::remove_if(timedEvents.begin(), timedEvents.end(),
    std::mem_fun(&AguiTimedEvent::expired), timedEvents.end());
std::for_each(toRun.begin(), toRun.end(), 
    std::mem_fun(&AguiTimedEvent::timedEventCallback));
std::for_each(toRun.begin(), toRun.end(), Deleter());
```

Note that this solution takes linear time, while yours takes quadradic time. This also cleanly gets rid of the issue that the callbacks might add to the new vector by removing the decisions about that until after the removal from the vector has already been done. On the other hand, it checks the `expired` flag twice, so if that's a complex operation this might be slower.