# Debug error: Vector iterator not dereferencable and Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to implement Rateless codes, but I have some issues in decoding.
In the first implementation I used iterator to loop over a vector of vector and do some operation (like *erase()*) but I was getting this debug error: **Vector iterator not dereferencable**.
After some googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504995/2296663) answer, so I switched from iterator to index, but I am facing the same problem and I do not know how to figure out. Now in debug mode I recive **Vector subscript out of range**.

Initialization of variables:

```
int k = 100;
int n = 150;
vector<int> output; // size of output is n
vector< vector<int> > relationship(n);
vector<int> decoded(k);
int counterDecodedSymbols = 0;
vector< vector<int> >::iterator it = relationship.begin();
vector<int>::iterator jt;
bool found = false;
```

First implementation with iterator:

```
    while (counterDecodedSymbols < k) {
    int counter0 = 0;
    for (it = relationship.begin(); it != relationship.end(); ++it) {       
        if (it->size() == 1) {
            ++counterDecodedSymbols;
            jt = it->begin();
            decoded[*jt] = output[it - relationship.begin()];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        ++counter0;
    }

    if (!found) {
        break;
    }

    int counter1 = 0;

    for (vector< vector<int> >::iterator zt = relationship.begin(); zt != relationship.end(); ++zt) {
        for (vector<int>::iterator kt = zt->begin(); kt != zt->end(); ++kt) {
            if (it == relationship.end()) {
                cout << "Ops" << endl;
            }
            if (*kt == *jt && zt != it) {
                output[zt - relationship.begin()] ^= output[it - relationship.begin()];
                if (zt->size() != 1) {
                    kt = zt->erase(kt);
                }
                else {
                    zt = relationship.erase(zt)
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (zt == relationship.end()) {
            cout << "Ops" << endl;
        }
        ++counter1;
    }
    it = relationship.erase(it);
}
```

Second one implementation with index:

```
int it = 0;
int jt = 0;

while (counterDecodedSymbols < k) {
    for (it = 0; it < relationship.size(); ++it) {
        if (relationship[it].size() == 1) {
            ++counterDecodedSymbols;
            jt = relationship[it][0];
            decoded[jt] = output[it];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        break;
    }

    for (int zt = 0; zt < relationship.size(); ++zt) {
        for (int kt = 0; kt < relationship[zt].size(); ++kt) {
            if (relationship[zt][kt] == relationship[it][0] && zt != it) {
                output[zt] ^= output[it];
                if (relationship[zt].size() != 1) {
                    relationship[zt].erase(kt + relationship[zt].begin());
                }
                else {
                    relationship.erase(zt + relationship.begin());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    relationship.erase(it + relationship.begin());
}
```

I recive one error (in the first implementation) here 
`for (vector< vector<int> >::iterator zt = relationship.begin(); zt != relationship.end(); ++zt) {`
With debugger I can see that `zt` size is `0`, `relationship` size is `54` and `counter1` (to see how many loop where done) is `55`.

I recive a second one error (in the first implementation) here
`if (*kt == *jt && zt != it) {`
`it` size now is `0`, `relationship` size is `33` and `counter0` is `33`.

So, the first time loop go over the size of `it` vector, and second time loop go over the size of `zt` vector.
I think the problem is connected to `erase` method, but I do not know how to fix it.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4504995/2296663) post, I tried to switch to index, but the issue is not over, I recive one error here 
`if (relationship[zt][kt] == relationship[it][0] && zt != it) {`
where `it` value is `149` and `relationship` size is `149`.

I hope I was clear.
Some one can put me in the right way?

Comment: Erasing from a vector while you're iterating over the same vector is a recipe for something to go wrong.  And why are you not debugging your code with a debugger?  Instead of guessing and/or trial and error, determine what is wrong by using a debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: This exactly the reason why I switched from iterator to index. Is with index the same?

Comment: `relationship[zt][kt] == relationship[it][0]`  You use `it`, which was declared and used way above where you have this line.  What is the value of `it` here?

Comment: As you can see from Question, when error turn on, `it` value is `149`. `relationship` size is `149`.

Comment: So what happens when you access `vector[149]` when the vector has only 149 elements?  The answer to that question may be what is wrong with your code.

Comment: It was clear that the problem is here, but I do not know WHY `it` is `149`.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just single step through your program to see why `it` is 149.  You say you're using the debugger, but your comments suggest you're not using it, or using it poorly.  Second, `it` is set in that first set of loops, therefore you should be investigating those loops.  This: `for (it = 0; it < relationship.size(); ++it)` means that `it` may equal `relationship.size()`, thus causing an issue with the second set of loops when you say `relationship[it][0]`.

Comment: I am checking your point, but how `it` can be equal to `relationship.size()` if loop end condition is `it < relationship.size()`?

Comment: `int i = 0; for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { }`  what is the value of `i` after the loop is executed?  Is it 10?  or is it 9?  It is 10.  So that's how `it` can be equal to `relationship.size()` when the loop terminates.

Comment: That was a right point. However it was just a collateral problem of `found`. Just need to update `found` to `false` when check `if (!found) {`. If `it` is equal to `relationship.size()` no one item has been found, so `found` must be at `false`. I forgot to update `found` after each loop for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add after

```
if (!found) {
    break;
}
```

that

```
else {
    found = false;
}
```

If `it` is equal `relationship.size()` that means that no one item has been found. Anyway, `found` was not updated to `false` after each for loop, so if it find just one time an item, it do `found = true`, and `found` keep the value `true` even if no one other item will be found in the next iterations.